# pyqtgraph requires Qt version >= 5.12

Tags: pyside2, pyqtgraph, shiboken2

I'am trying to plot in real time EEG data but I face some issues due to the use of pyqtgraph.

I've already try to upgrade pyside2 and shiboken2, to uninstall and install again, but it always end up the same way..

```
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui, QtCore
Exception: pyqtgraph requires Qt version >= 5.12  (your version is 5.9.7)
```

Does anyone know how should I solve that ?

Best,
K

Comment: Why didn't you also upgrade PyQt?

Answer (score 1):

Try `pip install pyqt5==5.12` for updating your Qt version.

Answer (score 0):

Just this cmd can help!

```
pip install pyqt5
```

Comment: Hi Fei! Welcome to Stack Overflow. When posting an answer, it's usually a good idea to give an explanation as well (see [answer]). In this instance, could you maybe explain why you believe installing pyqt5 will solve the problem ? The author already has a PyQt (pyside2) installed.